# Timer with Private Sub

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I have a `SignOff` sheet that at present runs a private sub. I am looking to also have the sheet close and save if left idle for more then 5 mins.

I am looking to combine the below, but cant seem to get them to run concurrently. Any help would be massively appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const PW = "" 'password to be specified

With Target
    If .Column = 10 And .Row > 1 And .CountLarge = 1 Then   
        .Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="" 'password to be specified
        If Len(.Value2) > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(, -1) = Now
            .Offset(, -2) = "Actioned by " & UserName
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        .Locked = True
        .Worksheet.Protect Password:=""'password to be specified
    End If
 End With
End Sub
```

With the below timer code

```
Const idleTime = 300 'seconds
Dim Start

Sub StartTimer()
Start = Timer
Do While Timer < Start + idleTime
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this VBA? I don't recognize vb.net.

Comment: Hi Mary, this is VBA. Thanks